# Конвертировать строку из textBox.Text в int и изменить значение при нажатии кнопки

Tags: android, c#, json, xamarin

Еcть Activity с описанием товара

Описание берется с Json

Есть кнопки "+" и "-", которые на данный момент изменяют количество товара.

Мне нужно чтоб по нажатию например на "+" помимо количества изменялась и цена

Как это реализовать?

Код:

```
private void ParseAndDisplay(JsonValue json)
        {


            int count = 1;

            ImageButton minus = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.minus);
            TextView counttext = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.counttext);
            ImageButton plus = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.plus);



            TextView productname = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.posttitle);
            TextView content = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.postcontent);
            TextView price = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.price);
            TextView weight = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.weight);
            ImageView imagen = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.image1);
            JsonValue firstitem = json[4];


            productname.Text = firstitem["post_title"];
            content.Text = firstitem["post_excerpt"];
        price.Text =  firstitem["price"] + "грн";
            weight.Text = firstitem["weight"] + "г";

            var imageBitmap2 = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(firstitem["img_url"]);
            imagen.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap2);
            plus.Click += delegate
        {
            counttext.Text = string.Format("{0}", ++count);
            int  price2 = Convert.ToInt32(price.Text); **здесь ошибка**
            price.Text = string.Format("{0}", ++price2);

        };  
            minus.Click += delegate
            {
                counttext.Text = string.Format("{0}", count > 1 ? --count : 1);
            };
```

Сам Json

```html
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 4533
            [post_author] => 4
            [post_date] => 2015-10-09 17:32:51
            [post_date_gmt] => 2015-10-09 13:32:51
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => Васаби
            [post_excerpt] => на 1 сушку 2гр; на 1 ролл 4 гр; на набор
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => open
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => vasabi
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2015-10-11 22:22:19
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2015-10-11 18:22:19
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://new.murakami.ua/shop/vasabi/
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => product
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
            [img_url] => http://new.murakami.ua/wp-content/uploads/Vasabi.jpg
            [visibility] => visible
            [price] => 7.00
            [weight] => 4
            [energy] => 
            [sku] => 822
            [category] => 90
        )
```

Comment: умножте цену на количество товара, получите стоимость.

Comment: @Eugene, текст ошибки какой?

Comment: @Eugene, А как мы должны были об этом догадаться?

Comment: @metalurgus, ну это же очевидно :-D Почти наверняка был _FormatException_

Comment: В общем, приведите свой JSON сюда, как минимум. А по-хорошему, надо заполнять модель из JSON'а, а потом уже работать с моделью

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.Плюс дополнил немного код. Сорри что вчера написал вопрос не развернуто @metalurgus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По хорошему бы вам работать с моделью данных. 
Исходя из того, что привели вы, попробуйте напрямую работать с UI, а далее уже делать с данными из UI все, что пожелаете.

Но вообще так делать не стоит ;)

Comment: Я собственно пробовал. Просто как я понимаю на моменте конвертации выдает ошибку System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Как её побороть не понимаю

Comment: @Eugene можете показать пример как вы работали с моделью ?

Comment: Пробовал , я имел ввиду , то что работаю с UI

Comment: @eugene на какой строке конкретно выдает ошибку ? Каким образом вы приводите тип переменной?

Comment: как я понимаю на этой:  int  price2 = Convert.ToInt32(price.Text);

Comment: @Eugene float.Parse("ваше значение", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: можно ли написать это так?   var price2 = float.Parse(price.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @Eugene да, можно.

Comment: заработало, так как я написал. Cпасибо большое

Comment: @eugene рад, что был вам полезен )

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32002/discussion-between-eugene-and--).

Answer (score 1):

Вы сначала делаете так:

```
price.Text =  firstitem["price"] + "грн";
```

после чего у вас `Price.Text` равняется `7.00грн`, а после этого делаете

```
int  price2 = Convert.ToInt32(price.Text);
```

То, что возникает ошибка - просто очевидно. Во первых, каким образом вы хотите в число перевести `7.00грн`? Во вторых, с чего вы взяли, что цена должна быть типа `int`? Она не может быть `7.50`? Для денег используйте как минимум `double`, а цену парсите из `JSON`а, а не из текста поля, в которое уже добавили `ГРН`

Comment: проблема уже давно решена

Comment: @Eugene, тем не менее, ответы не содержали ответа на ваш вопрос, как такового.

Comment: я опубликую сейчас

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто вписать это

```
     float price2 = float.Parse(price.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```